# Difference in output between Command Prompt looking terminal and VSC Terminal

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

I recently started learning C and have just started using VSC. I was previously using CodeBlocks. While testing out a simple array program, I realised that there is a difference in output. For reference, the array program code is shown below.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    
    int grades[10];
    int count = 10;
    long sum;
    float average;
    
    printf("\nPlease enter the 10 grades: \n");
    //printf("%i", count);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    
    printf("%2u> ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &grades[i]);
    sum += grades[i];
    };

average = (float)sum/count;
printf("The average of the 10 grades are %.2f", average);
return 0;

}
```

I am able to run the for loop but the code after the for loop does not appear in the CMD like terminal and the program just quits after the for loop. However, the code after the for loop does appear in the VSC terminal. I am able to enter the ten values.

The VSC Terminal Output: [image: The VSC Terminal output manages to print out the codes after the for loop]

However, the CMD looking terminal did not manage to print the code after the for loop and instead exits the program.

Could it be because of this error: "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1." everytime I click 'Run > Start Debugging'.

Sorry for this messy format but thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: You never initialize the variable `sum`. Its value will be *indeterminate* (look at it as garbage):

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for being ignorant but while I was trying to debug, I placed the code after the for loop before it and it managed to print out on the CMD looking terminal. It also managed to print out in CodeBlocks with the code in the post.

Comment: On an unrelated note: You don't need an array here for this assignment, Only a single `int` variable which you use for the `scanf` call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see but I am currently following some lesson on array and as such here I am

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on the problem: Do your program run the loop, do you input the ten values? Does it "crash" or exit after the input loop? Or can't you run the program at all?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hello, I have edited my post and answered the questions which you have asked! Thank you for your insight!